# jQuery conflict between click and touchstart/touchend

Tags: jquery, click, conflict

I have a section that detects the touchstart and touchend (it works), but I have a link that doesn't detect the click.

What's happening?

#main uses overflow. Is that the problem?

```js
$("#main").on("touchstart, touchend", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  console.log("touch zone>");
})

$(document).on("click", "#main a", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  console.log("Button click");
});
```

```css
#main {
  width: 40vh;
  height: 90vh;
  overflow: hidden auto;
  background: Gray;
}
```

```html
<section id="main">
  <h1>Title demo <a href="#">Link</a></h1>
  <p>Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem</p>

  <h1>Title demo <a href="#">Link</a></h1>
  <p>Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem</p>

  <h1>Title demo <a href="#">Link</a></h1>
  <p>Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem</p>

  <h1>Title demo <a href="#">Link</a></h1>
  <p>Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem</p>

  <h1>Title demo <a href="#">Link</a></h1>
  <p>Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem</p>

  <h1>Title demo <a href="#">Link</a></h1>
  <p>Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem</p>
</section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchors are for navigation and buttons are for actions.  Be sure you're using the correct element for the task. You may style them as desired.

That may help also by eliminating the need for `preventDefault()`, which I believe is the problem.

Other tips:

- A section [shouldn't have more than one level 1 heading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements#usage_notes). It should have one primary heading describing the section and level 2 headings describing subsections.
- Don't use inline styles. They make your document messy and less maintainable, tend to result in repetition, and aren't reusable.

```js
$("#main").on("touchstart, touchend", () => {
  console.log("touch zone");
})

$(document).on("click", "#main button", () => {
  console.log("Button click");
});
```

```css
.main {
  width: 40vh;
  height: 90vh;
  overflow: hidden auto;
  background: Gray;
}
```

```html
<section id="main" class="main">
  <h1>Title demo <button>Action</button></h1>
  <p>Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem</p>
  <h1>Title demo <button>Action</button></h1>
  <p>Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem</p>
  <h1>Title demo <button>Action</button></h1>
  <p>Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem</p>
  <h1>Title demo <button>Action</button></h1>
  <p>Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem</p>
  <h1>Title demo <button>Action</button></h1>
  <p>Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem</p>
</section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: One more question, I can't access the botton attributes, it gives me "undefined". My code is: $(this).attr("href") or this.nodeName.

how do i solve it?

Comment: Please don't ask new questions in comments. There's nothing in that snippet that shows a problem. Post a new question or have a look at the many existing questions on that topic.